# Pandas GroupBy Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that I want to groupby.  Within each group, I want to perform a check to see if the first values is less than the second value times some scalar, e.g. (x < y * .5).  If it is, the first value is set to True and all other values False.  Else, all values are False.

I have a sample data frame here:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                           [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                           [1.25, 10.1, 2.3, 2.4, 1.2, 5.5, 5.7]]).T,
                          columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I can get a stacked groupby to get the data that I want out a `a`:

```
g = d.groupby('a')['c'].nsmallest(2).groupby(level='a')
```

This results in three groups, each with 2 entries.  By adding an `apply`, I can call a function to return a boolean mask:

```
def func(group):
    if group.iloc[0] < group.iloc[1] * .5:
        return [True, False]
    else:
        return [False, False]

g = d.groupby('a')['c'].nsmallest(2).groupby(level='a').apply(func)
```

Unfortunately, this destroys the index into the original dataframe and removes the ability to handle cases where more than 2 elements are present.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to maintain the index in the original dataframe and update a column with the results of a groupby?  This is made slightly different because the `.nsmallest` call results in a Series on the 'c' column.
2. Does a more elegant method exist to compute a boolean array for groups in a dataframe based on some custom criteria, e.g. this ratio test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) is what you need:

```
>>> def func(group):
...     res = [False] * len(group)
...     if group.iloc[0] < group.iloc[1] * .5:
...         res[0] = True
...     return res
>>> d['res'] = d.groupby('a')['c'].transform(func).astype('bool')
>>> d
   a  b      c    res
0  0  3   1.25   True
1  0  4  10.10  False
2  1  5   2.30  False
3  1  6   2.40  False
4  2  7   1.20   True
5  2  8   5.50  False
6  2  9   5.70  False
```

From the documentation:

> The transform method returns an object that is indexed the same (same
>   size) as the one being grouped. Thus, the passed transform function
>   should return a result that is the same size as the group chunk. For
>   example, suppose we wished to standardize the data within each group

Comment: Worked as advertised.  I had not realized that transform could take an arbitrary function (missed it in the docs).  Thanks!